# Are the last few days of a year excluded in selecting 2023年国内国际新闻?

Tags: culture

To my surprise, yesterday (Dec 27, 2023), major media outlets like Xinhua and CCTV announced their choices of top 10 domestic and international news items respectively.

I don't want to say too much on the exclusion of the death of Premier Li Keqiang and the recent earthquake in Gansu and Qinghai provinces, which in my opinion definitely deserves a top 10 place by all means.

But what confuses me most is that how come a list is complete for a whole year when there are still a few days to reach the end of the Year 2023. **Why are they so sure that in the last few days nothing of great importance will occur?** I notice that the statistics of GDP is not released until March next year to include everything of the last year.

What culture is that?

Comment: It is how we do things. If you wait until March 2024 to release "top 10 news of 2023" it would not be of too much interest to people.

Comment: If you google "top stories 2023" you will also find a lot of hits from western media. So it's not something unusual to me.

Comment: "What culture is that?" A culture different from yours?